# How to tell where my Instance is located?

Tags: instance

NA is North America, EU is Europe/Middle East, ..etc.

I am curious as to where the NAXX numbers are specifically located. For instance (no pun intended), NA23 would be located on the east or west coast? Salesforce has to have this documented somewhere. I have the same questions for the sandbox instances (CSXX).

Comment: I'm 100% sure that data is stored in at least 2 different physical locations, so the question isn't relevant and at specific point of time they could return it from different locations, or might have an algorithms to select the fastest by user's IP

Comment: @Oleksiy If you know of where this is documented, that would be awesome. I believe what you are saying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do a DNS lookup on your salesforce hostname and it will be an alias to a hostname that contains the datacenter in it. Note that these can change during failover operations and maybe for other reasons.

For example, NA2 is currently hosted in CHI:

```
$ nslookup na2.salesforce.com                    

Non-authoritative answer:                        
Name:    na2-chi.salesforce.com                  
Addresses:  96.43.146.48                         
          96.43.146.176                          
Aliases:  na2.salesforce.com
```

Note the na2-**chi**. That would be the *CHI* airport code - so somewhere in Chicago.

Again for [cs6](http://ping.eu/nslookup/):

> cs6.salesforce.com is an alias for cs6-tyo.salesforce.com.
>   cs6-tyo.salesforce.com has address 182.50.78.35
>   cs6-tyo.salesforce.com has address 182.50.78.163

So *TYO* - Tokyo.

Interestingly enough, the location based on the [IP address alone](http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/182.50.78.35) is Singapore.

*This is not a documented behavior and may be subject to change. If you need an authoritative answer you should contact your account exec/support.

Comment: See also - Knowledge Article [Where is my Salesforce instance located?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000257307&language=en_US&type=1)

Answer (score 3):

There are three North American data centers for salesforce.com that have been publicly announced, although that was about 10 years ago now. Two of those data centers are for backup and disaster recovery purposes, and just one data center actually powers all of the instances named ssl (the classic salesforce.com instance), and na1 through naXX (whatever the current number is). All of the data you access directly whenever you log in or use the API is coming from San Jose, near the West Coast. In the event that this data center were to become permanently unavailable, there is a data center on the East Coast as backup. It is mirrored in real time using an OC64 (*very* fast) connection, as outlined in the [Mirrorforce](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000006tbm) idea. The only servers not located in the United States are those serving Eurasia and Japan.

Comment: I believe na0/ssl.salesforce.com is finally being decommissioned and no longer hosts traffic. The SJC datacenter is much less prominent than it used to be as well; multiple active US datacenters have replaced it.

Answer (score 3):

Additionally you can look at the official documentation from Salesforce as to the locale of the servers:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000257307&type=1

But as ca_peterson said, to find the specific city (since the data centre rotate every 6 months between the two locations listed) you'll need to do the DNS lookup