# Where is my server located?

Tags: instance

Does anyone know where my Instance server is located? My organisation is located in Berlin, Europe.

Comment: This might help you.Please visit the below link:
[http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/64616/how-to-get-salesforce-instance-url](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/64616/how-to-get-salesforce-instance-url)

Comment: Actually [this](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/121309/how-to-tell-where-my-instance-is-located) is what they're asking, I think.

Comment: I don't think any of the mentioned duplicates is what the asker is asking. The question is: "Where is my instance located?" So I'm assuming a physical location  (country/city) is wanted.

Comment: @Guy isn't that what the post I linked to discusses?

Comment: Hmm the question is indeed almost equal but I found the answers given rather technical e.g. when using nslookup, eu4.salesforce.com is reported to be located in eu4-frf.frf.salesforce.com. So maybe I should move my answer there..

Answer (score 3):

Officially SFDC does not tell you where your instance is located, as it is a 'software-as-a-service'. However, you could do a ip lookup on your url to find out.

E.g. via https://www.iplocation.net/ I found out that eu1.salesforce.com (and also any other EU server I checked) is located in Staines, UK.

As a general rule-of-thumb SFDC assigns customers to a data center that is closest to the customer location.

Also note that SFDC might change the location of your instance in the future. New data centers are opening in France and Germany, so you might move there in the coming years.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using a custom domain name then it will have the Salesforce node in the URL, e.g.

> https://cs26.salesforce.com/setup/forcecomHomepage.apexp?setupid=ForceCom&retURL=%2Fhome%2Fhome.jsp

is on node cs26

There is no site where it is explicitly stated where Salesforce nodes are hosted as the EU nodes are primarily hosted in the UK data centre but failover and backup is not necessarily going to another EU data centre.

[Trust Data Centres](http://content.trust.salesforce.com/trust/en/learn/datacenter/) on the trust.salesforce.com site does not mention locations or any mapping of nodes to sites.

The [compliance](http://content.trust.salesforce.com/trust/en/learn/compliance/) part of the trust site mentions Safe Harbour and its other certifications.